# Including stdio and stddef

Tags: c, syntax, stdio

I m currently preparing a C certification, in the course material relating to pointer NULL, there is this line whch trouble me:

> if you want to use the NULL symbol you have to **include one of the following header files:** stdio.h **or** stddef.h. The NULL symbol is defined in there.

(Bold are in the source)

Since the `or` is emphasized, I read it as "never include both". Is it a real norm or is it just one of the (many) flaws in the course material?

Comment: Maybe they wanted to emphasize that it is an or and no xor ;)

Comment: By convention, OR is inclusive, so you should read "A or B" as "either A or B, or both A and B".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include either one or both. The one to be written first will declare NULL as the first and it wont be declared twice.

Answer (score 2):

It is useless to include both since `stdio.h` includes `stddef.h`. But you can include both if you want, since there is a guard to avoid multiple inclusions.

Answer (score 1):

the official place for NULL to be defined is in `<stddef.h>`. However, on most implementations, you can include `<stdio.h>` or `<string.h>` (or quite a few other includes) to pick it up.

It is quite safe to include both, and you should so so if you actually need them (and contrariwise, you shouldn't include `<stdio.h>` if you don't need it).